# Classifying data in R

Tags: r, classification, svm

I'm using R and I want to use some type of machine learning technique (SVM, perhaps) to classify data. I have data that looks like this, for example

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    4    5    6    0
[2,]    2    6    7    3    1
[3,]    7    1    4    6    1
[4,]    3    4    5    9    0
```

Where columns 1, 2, 3, and 4 are variables with some provided data, and column 5 is the classification. So, data entry 1 has values 3, 4, 5, and 6 for the four variables, and is classified as a 0. Classifications can be either 0 or 1. I want to be able to build an SVM so that given a new set of variables, it will classify it as "0" or "1"

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Depending on how you interpret it, this is a very broad question or a coding question (which is not appropriate on this site). Regarding the latter, a Google search for “SVM R” seem to return useful results.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a question for CrossValidated, but here is a primer for doing that in R:

```
groups <- factor( a[,5] )
train  <- a[,-5]
library( kernlab )
ksvm.model <- ksvm( train, groups )
```

There are other options, though. There are numerous supervised machine learning algorithms, and it is not possible to say which one is best. In my hands and in the context of my data, SVM perform worse than random forests (package `randomForest` in R) or partial least squares discriminant analysis (PLS-DA, R package e.g. `mixOmics`).